# mysql using count, and distinct count

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I was asked this question earlier, and not being able to answer it has been bothering me..

Lets say we have a table with clients and their city of residence.

What if I wanted to query for the unique number of cities, AS WELL as how many times each city appears.

To be more clear:

```
Toronto
Toronto
Toronto
Oshawa
Oshawa
```

```
Distinct cities: 2
Toronto: 3
Oshawa: 2
```

The answer is probably simple, my mind is just mush at the moment!

Answer (score 3):

This will return a row for each city, containing the city name and the number of times the city appears:

```
SELECT 
    city,
    COUNT(*) 
FROM clients
GROUP BY city
```

The total number of cities is just the number of rows returned by the query. If you really want it to appear on the recordset, I can think of two ways (none of which I particularly like).

1. UNION query:

   ```
   SELECT 'CITIES' as city, COUNT(DISTINCT city) 
   FROM clients
   UNION
   SELECT city, COUNT(*) 
   FROM clients
   GROUP BY city
   ```
2. Subquery on the `SELECT` clause:

   ```
   SELECT 
     (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT city)) AS all, 
     city,
     COUNT(*) 
   FROM clients
   GROUP BY city
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Use a group by for this.

```
select city, count(*) from clients group by city
```

Comment: absolutely, thanks so much, cant believe I could not to think of that!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the sql for selecting the distinct cities:

```
select distinct city from Clients;
```

Here's the sql for selecting the names along with how many there are:

```
select city, count(*) from Clients group by city;
```